# Run linux command on remote server by slash command on rocketchat

Tags: rocket.chat

I want to create user on a remote Linux server by slash command on `rocktchat`
for example:

`/createuser USERNAME`

then USRNAME created on my Linux server (or any other command)
I use `rocketchat` version 6.2.0

Please guide me fully
thank you.